# Should Flight.js component instances make use of shared variables?

Tags: javascript, twitter-flight

I am just getting started with [Flight.js](https://github.com/flightjs/flight) and realized that component instances share local variables, but didn't find anything about it in the documentation.

This is what i mean:

```
flight.component(function () {

    var sharedBetweenAllInstances = true;

    this.notShared = true;

}).attachTo('.multiple-elements');
```

As example, if a component should count clicks on it, it could increment `this.clicksCount` for the number of clicks on each single instance, and increment `var totalClicks` for the total number of clicks on any instance of the component.

I didn't find anything about this in the documentation, so I wonder if flight components should be used this way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's a good idea (probably why they don't mention it in the docs). The function you setup as your "component" is actually applied as a functional mixin, along with any other mixins your component uses. So, while you might be able to access that variable when doing an `.attachTo('.multip-selector')` where you're setting up an instance on each of many components, you could still run into problem if attaching individually, or if the shared variable controls resources in which a race condition to access that shared resource becomes problematic.

From a "component" standpoint, you're better off pulling out any shared state into a separate data component or controller type component that can receive updates form the individual components and broadcast the shared state when it's updated.

Here's an example I put together using that scenario via jsbin:  http://jsbin.com/qecupi/edit?js

Comment: Thank you, I'll go for the separate data component!